# how to save a variable that keep alive for all time in PHP (or in MySql)

Tags: php, mysql, variables, var

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable LIMIT [startpoint], [row_count]
```

I want this `startpoint` variable to be keep alive for all time irrespective of any thing i.e ideal condition the variable should be alive and keep changing itself based on logic until some thing happen to application or web server. Is it possible or i have to write it to a file and read it or save to a table and read it.

Comment: Since you want a variable that should be modified globally for your whole application, yes, the best thing to do would be to save it in a file or database

Comment: You want this variable to be stored constantly while you are the website or do you want it to be possible to return to this point when you get back again?

Comment: Databases are designed to do the job, but to be dynamically changing, you need to code by yourself the "actions" that update the variable.

Comment: but my problem is it will be changing for every thirty seconds so (i am logging activity into file) so every day the records will increase apart from that is there any way to keep my variable alive

Comment: then keep it in database and set a cron job to update it every thirty seconds.

Comment: What about using a date in the table, and then applying a calculation to the date in the table, that figures out the final number. The final number can then be a variable to use in your actuall script? This way you dont have to update it every 30 seconds, but it updates whenever you hit refresh and calculates from the date you set

Answer (score 1):

PHP variables will only live for as long as their script is being executed.
If you change the value of startpoint dynamically you'll have to store it either in a file or a database.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use session-variables or cookies perhaps?
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php
http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

Comment: there is a problem with paging values being stored in session because what if the user opens two windows all your paging going to go wrong.

Comment: That is completely true. I personally would use cookies then or if I want to be lazy and ineffective - text files.

Answer (score 0):

Use file storage to do it, it's the fastest way.
You can get when the file was changed using `getLastChanged(filename);`

```
function setGlob($name,$val)
{
    file_put_contents("glob_$name",$val);
}

function getGlob($name)
{
    return file_get_contents("glob_".$name);
}

function getLastChanged($name)
{
    return filemtime("glob_".$name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scope of a php variable is limited to the execution of current page or sequence.
you should either save it in a config file or in the DB to access it  for multiple requests.

Answer (score 0):

variables only keep their value as long as it's script is executing. If you want to use that variable value for the current session (untill browser does not closed) you can use **[SESSION](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)** Or if you want to keep as long as you want then use **[COOKIES](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp)**